# Php system news - Add Social Share Buttons

Tags: php

i made a php system for adding, modify and delete news on a website.

It works with a normal While cycle.

```
    <?php
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $titolo = htmlentities($row['titolo']);
    $contenuto = html_entity_decode($row['contenuto']);
$autore = htmlentities($row['autore']);
$settimana = $arr_set[date("w", strtotime($row["data"]))];
$giorno = date("d", strtotime($row["data"]));
$mese = $arr_mesi[date("n", strtotime($row["data"]))-1];
$anno = date("Y", strtotime($row["data"]));

$data = "".$settimana."&nbsp;".$giorno."&nbsp;".$mese."&nbsp;".$anno."";

    ?>
    <table style="width:100%;" class="tabella_news">
    <tr>
    <td><?php echo "<h3>".$titolo."</h3>"; ?></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td><?php echo "<p class=\"autore\"><strong>Articolo scritto da:</strong> ".$autore."</p>"; ?></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td><?php echo "<p class=\"data\"><strong>In data:</strong> ".$data."</p>"; ?></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td><?php echo "<div class=\"contenuto_news\">".$contenuto."</div>"; ?></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>
    <span class='st_facebook_vcount' displayText='Facebook'></span>
    <span class='st_twitter_vcount' displayText='Tweet'></span>
    <span class='st_googleplus_vcount' displayText='Google +'></span>
    </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td><div class="divider"></div></td>
    </tr>
    <?php
     }
    ?>
    </table>
```

Works perfect with no problems and it show 3 news per page.
Now, they ask me to add the possibility to share EVERY news on Facebook, Twitter and Google+.

How can i do it?
I tried to add a new row inside the while cycle with the sharethis.com buttons, but when i go to share it show (obviously) the link of the page (news.php).

How can i show only the single news?

Comment: try ADDTHIS shear buttons http://www.addthis.com/

Comment: I't does the same of sharethis.com

I don't know how to modify the code to show only the single article instead the entire page.